# unable to run remote ssh commands with expect script

Tags: linux, ssh, tcl, expect

I am unable to run commands on remote host using expect script.It just logs in to the remote host and exits.Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 15
puts "connecting to the storage\n"
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set host [lindex $argv 1]
set pass "root123"
spawn ssh "$user\@$host"
expect {
"Password: " {
send "$pass\r"
sleep 1
expect {
"$ " {
  send "isi quota quotas list|grep ramesh\r" }
"$ " {
  send "exit\r" }

}
}
"(yes/no)? " {
send "yes\r"
expect {
"$ " { send "ls\r" }
"$ " { send "exit\r" }

"> " {}
}
}
default {
send_user "login failed\n"
exit 1
}
}
```

It only gets into the remote host and exits.
    [deep@host1:~]$ ./sshexpect user1 host2
    connecting to the storage

```
spawn ssh user1@host2
Password:
host2$
[deep@host1:~]$
```

Is the syntax wrong?
I am new to tcl scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation would help a lot:

```
expect {
    "Password: " {
        send "$pass\r"
            sleep 1
            expect {
                "$ " { send "isi quota quotas list|grep ramesh\r" }
                "$ " { send "exit\r" }
            }
    }
    "(yes/no)? " {
        send "yes\r"
            expect {
                "$ " { send "ls\r" }
                "$ " { send "exit\r" }
                "> " {}
            }
    }
    default {
        send_user "login failed\n"
            exit 1
    }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
            expect {
                "$ " { send "isi quota quotas list|grep ramesh\r" }
                "$ " { send "exit\r" }
            }
```

You're matching the same pattern twice: I suspect expect is ignoring the first action block, and just using the 2nd one;
 thus you exit immediately.

This is what you want to do:

```
expect {
    "(yes/no)? " { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
    "Password: " { send "$pass\r"; exp_continue }
    timeout      { send_user "login failed\n"; exit 1 }
    -re {\$ $}
}
send "isi quota quotas list|grep ramesh\r"

expect -re {\$ $}
send "ls\r"

expect -re {\$ $}
send "exit\r"

expect eof
```

Comment: I understood the mistake, but I didnt get what does the below line stands for
    -re {\$ $}
And also why do we need to put 
    expect eof
at the end of the script

Comment: The `-re` option uses regular expression pattern instead of the default glob patterns. I'm specifying that the prompt is a dollar sign and a space *at the end of the line*. If expect sees a dollar sign and a space and then some other text, that won't match as a prompt. `expect eof` basically means "wait until the spawned process is closed" -- not strictly necessary here, but generally good practice.

Comment: I tried that still doesnt work for me.It shows the "login failed" and exits.
It just logs into the remote box and then blank and after sometime exits with "login failed"

Comment: run your script with `expect -d filename` to enable debug output. expect will tell you why none of the patterns match.

Comment: I got it! Works for me now